# Code to update records for both initcap and upper

Tags: oracle, plsql, capitalization

I am trying to update records that have both initcap and upper case letters. For example : Stages Home Health LLC; Dana Ash

It has both Initcap "Stages" and Upper which is "LLC"

I have tried using and with a where clause, but have not gotten the result needed

select bbl_id, entity_name from bbl_dq_test where entity_name =

UPPER (ENTITY_NAME) AND ENTITY_NAME = INITCAP (ENTITY_NAME);

but I am looking for something that resembles

**update bbl_dq_test A
set Text_field_format = 'BOTH'
where entity_name = ( A clause that finds Initcap and Upper together)**

select bbl_id, entity_name from bbl_dq_test where entity_name =

UPPER (ENTITY_NAME) AND ENTITY_NAME = INITCAP (ENTITY_NAME);

Only returns numbers.

Comment: First obvious question: WHY are you trying to do whatever it is that you are trying to do? Is that the actual assignment from business users, or is it just part of a solution you are trying for the actual problem? If it's the latter, it may be helpful to state the problem you are ultimately trying to solve. Then - how should you handle an input such as `BMG GmbH`? Obviously `GmbH` is neither uppercase nor initcap. (GmbH is German for LLC)

Comment: Also: Does a single-letter "word" constitute an "uppercase" word? What if, for example, you had the input "D Steele Corp"? Do you need to find this? Or something like "Steele Advisors L.L.C."? More generally - how do you want to handle punctuation (as in L.L.C.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REGEXP_LIKE could be helpful here:

The query below is a starting point.  The regex patterns might need to be tweaked to ensure that they cover all the desired cases - and consider the input values mentioned by commenters on the original post.

```
SELECT *
  FROM  bbl_dq_test
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(entity_name, '(^[A-Z][a-z]| [A-Z][a-z])')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(entity_name, '(^[A-Z]+ | [A-Z]+ | [A-Z]+$)');
```

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501